# Python 3/Pandas Dataframe Splitting a column in multiple columns with binary values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm wondering about the cleanest way to do what I'm facing.
i'd like to create a new column for every value of a column in an existing dataframe. I don't know how many values can exist and for every line we would need to put all the values to 0 except if the option was toogled, which in this case would be 1.
Ok that might not be easy to understand so I'll try to make an example with pseudo code too:

Let's imagine I have such a DataFrame:

```
|    Name    ||    Surname   ||    Color    ||    Genre      |

|    Paul    ||    hellppp   ||    Blue     ||    Male     |
|    Erik    ||    meeeeee   ||    Red      ||    Woman    |
|    Igor    ||    plllsss   ||    Green    ||    Male     |
```

Should become

```
|    Name    ||    Surname   ||    Red    ||    Blue      |    Green     |    Male      |    Woman      

|    Paul    ||    hellppp   ||    0      ||    1         |    0         |    1         |    0      
|    Erik    ||    meeeeee   ||    1      ||    0         |    0         |    0         |    1 
|    Igor    ||    plllsss   ||    0      ||    0         |    1         |    1         |    0
```

So basically for now I created an array containing all my qualitative values list so basically this:

```
qualitative_data = ['Color', 'Genre']
```

And now I'm willing to do something like:

```
for x in qualitative_data:
           pass
```

Comment: I don't understant it: `df.set_index(['Name','Surname']).pivot_table(index=['Name','Surname'],columns=['Color','Genre'],aggfunc='nunique',fill_value=0).reset_index()` vs `df.pivot_table(index=['Name','Surname'],columns=['Color','Genre'],aggfunc='nunique',fill_value=0).reset_index()`....

Comment: @ansev That would be better posed as its own question. Basically it boils down to how `GroupBy.nunique` still returns unique counts (guaranteed to be 1) for grouping columns, though it does not do so if a grouping column is part of the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
result = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Color', 'Genre'], prefix_sep='', prefix='')

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   Name  Surname  Blue  Green  Red  Male  Woman
0  Paul  hellppp     1      0    0     1      0
1  Erik  meeeeee     0      0    1     0      1
2  Igor  plllsss     0      1    0     1      0
```

Comment: please look at my comment in the question, I still don't understand the result of this in the panda library

Comment: @ansev What do you mean?

Comment: why does pandas do this? it's not logical